# How to fix the logic to add the leading zeros on the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to convert my user's input data into following range XX.XXXXXX by adding leading and trailing zeros based on the data. Using the snippet below, how can I correct the logic so that it adds the leading zero to the following data samples provided below:

Link for sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-62680234-formatdecimal-gc9bo?file=/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const handleChange = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    let dataFormatted =
      val < 1 || val >= 10 ? (+val).toFixed(6) : "0" + (+val).toFixed(6);
    console.log("dataFormatted: ", dataFormatted);
  };
  return <input onChange={handleChange} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Current behavior:**

```
".12", converts into ".120000"
"-1.1", converts into "-1.100000"
"-1.23" converts into "-1.230000"
```

**Expected behavior:**

```
".12" should convert it to "00.120000"
"-1.1", should allow to input "-01.100000"
"-1.23", should allow to input "-01.230000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.padStart` and `String.prototype.padEnd`:

```
  const handleChange = e => {
    let [left, right] = e.target.value.split('.');
    right = right.padEnd(6, "0");
    left = left[0] !== '-' ? left.padStart(2, "0") : "-" + left.slice(1).padStart(2, "0");
    const value = [left,right].join(".")
    console.log(value)
    
  };
```

Comment: I am getting an error "Cannot read property 'padEnd' of undefined" on line `right = right.padEnd(6, "0");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the ternary operator, I'd start by determining if the number is positive or negative. In case it's negative, prepend the string by '-' and do an additional check if the absolute value of that number is below 10, in which case you have to add a "0" to the string.

Here's an example:

```js
function format(val) {
  return Math.sign(val) == -1 ? Math.abs(val) > 10 ? "-" + Math.abs(val).toFixed(6) : "-0" + Math.abs(val).toFixed(6) : Math.abs(val) > 10 ? Math.abs(val).toFixed(6) : "0" + Math.abs(val).toFixed(6);
}

let valA = .12;
let valB = -1.1;
let valC = -1.23;

let dataFormatted = format(valA);
console.log("dataFormatted: ", dataFormatted);

dataFormatted = format(valB);
console.log("dataFormatted: ", dataFormatted);

dataFormatted = format(valC);
console.log("dataFormatted: ", dataFormatted);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution works really well. Wondering is it possible to handle data entry of `0` (including `0.0` or `0.00` or `0.000` or `00.000000`) as being an invalid input. For example, when I enter just `0` to the input it should not convert into the format `00.000000`?

Comment: What should happen if the user enters 0?

Comment: it should not convert into the proper format and hence, throw an error to the user that it's unacceptable input. I can handle the validation if you can just help me out to prevent `0` from formatting.